# printf implementation for embedded system

Tags: embedded, printf

where can I find an almost complete implementation (float, width, etc.) suitable for embedded systems (few nested funtction call, low stack and ram usage, no heap, mo syscall)

Comment: you look at newlib?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out ChibiOS's implementation of [chvprintf](http://chibios.sourceforge.net/html/group__chprintf.html)? It's Apache-licensed and float-support (costly) is a compile-time option via `define`.

It's built with microcontrollers in mind. The macros are all pretty much only calls to a function pointer in the supplied BaseSequentialStream struct and you can replace them as you see fit. The var-args list is your regular `stdarg.h` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For transmitting on the serial port, the quickest thing is:

```
int32_t printfDebugSerial(const char *format, ...)
{
  if (strlen(format) >200) return -1;
  char tempBuff[256]; memset(tempBuff, 0, sizeof tempBuff);

  va_list arg;
  int32_t done;
  va_start (arg, format);
  done = (int32_t)vsprintf(tempBuff,format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  pushMsgOnSerial((uint8_t*)tempBuff, done);
  return done;
}
```

where `pushMsgOnSerial()` will be your board specific function for sending bytes on the serial port.